# toast message not appearing when triggered from flow

Tags: visual-workflow, aura, toast

[image]I have a lightning flow embedded in the case record page where I collect some dummy data from input screen and fire the toast message from Flow . I have created the aura component and called the aura component in th flow action and  supplied the message and type of message. but when I run the flow the flow is running without any error and refresh is happening but the message is not showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [developer forum post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IT04) I was able to achieve the above implementation using the lightning component code in this [article](https://unofficialsf.com/show-toast-flow-action/#:%7E:text=Version%202.0%20adds%20the%20ability,pop%20up%20a%20toast%20message.).

Can you try checking the lightning component code against the above one?

Comment: thank you this example works like a charm

Comment: Glad to know it worked Prasanth.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achive this using code mentioned here. -> https://salesforcecodex.com/salesforce/custom-toast-with-custom-duration-in-lwc/

Here, we have added *Custom Toast*. And this will work as a work around very well.